# Kubernetes nginx-ingress verify-depth value doesn't match verified certs

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, mtls

When using client certs authentication on nginx-ingress the `auth-tls-verify-depth` annotation doesn't honor the number provided. Based on the documentation when I set the number of 2 I expect that mTLS will fail when having client certificate signed by intermediate CA which is 3rd in order from CA (clien_cert <- intermediate1 <- intermediate2 <- CA), but unfortunately that is not the case and mTLS verification works. By the documentation the above scenario should work only with `auth-tls-verify-depth` set to 3 or more..

I was able to find out that with OpenSSL 1.1.0+ it behaves a bit differently - https://github.com/nginx/nginx-tests/blob/7a9e95fdd30729540ee9650be7f991c330367d5b/ssl_verify_depth.t#L145

If nginx-ingress is following the above procedure I would expect that to be written specifically in the doc, which is not currently. So I am not sure if it is bug within nginx-ingress or it works as expected

Having:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "2"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: <namespace>/CA_certificate
```

I was expecting HTTP 400 Bad Request - SSL Certificate Error

But I am getting HTTP 200 with mTLS working.